# Disabling remote access to PHPMyAdmin 4.7.4

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

I allowed remote access to PHPMyAdmin in the past and now I'm attempting to disable it. I've edited the C:\wamp64\alias\phpmyadmin.conf file to look like this:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.7.4/"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.7.4/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride all

    <ifDefine APACHE24>

    </ifDefine>

    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
    </ifDefine>

    # To import big file you can increase values
    php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
    php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
    php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
    php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

However it still allows remote access to PHPMyAdmin. What should I change?
(I'm using WampServer 3.1.0 for Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the C:\wamp64\alias\phpmyadmin.conf file to:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.7.4/"

<Directory "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.7.4/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride all

    <ifDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
    </ifDefine>

    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
    </ifDefine>

    # To import big file you can increase values
    php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
    php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
    php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
    php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```